# phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility not detecting error

Tags: php, phpcs

I am trying to check for errors via phpcs and PHPCompatibility standard on a laravel project, here is the command:

```
phpcs -psvw app --extensions=php --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 8.0
```

The command works fine. However, I am supposed to receive following error but I am not:

`Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in somefile.php on line 838`

The actual code where PHP8 fails but PHPCS does not inform:

```
$results[] = is_null($dependency->getClass()) ? $this->resolvePrimitive($dependency) : $this->resolveClass($dependency);
```

The reason PHPCompatibility standard should tell me about this error is that when I try to run my app in PHP 8 I get above error, however PHPCS with PHPCompatibility does not report above error.

Any idea how can I make PHPCompatibility report above error ?

Comment: When posting a question, please show us a _concrete_ and _actual_ example of your issue instead of telling us to "ignore that and imagine if".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Here is problematic code: `$results[] = is_null($dependency->getClass()) ? $this->resolvePrimitive($dependency) : $this->resolveClass($dependency);`. Updated in question too.